# New issue acknowleging Walmart Seller Orders

Tags: walmart-api

We are experiencing error all of a student while attempting to acknowledge orders, this started last week

Here is a sample post and result, everything else seems to work fine, getting Orders, shipping orders and updating inventory

the request sample is

https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders/4800779811910/acknowledge/v3/orders/4800779811910/acknowledge

The error is

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?><ns2:errors xmlns:ns2=""http://walmart.com/""><ns2:error><ns2:code>SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_GATEWAY_API</ns2:code><ns2:info>System encountered some internal error.</ns2:info><ns2:severity>ERROR</ns2:severity><ns2:category>DATA</ns2:category><ns2:causes/><ns2:errorIdentifiers/></ns2:error></ns2:errors>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the request URL be https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders/4800779811910/acknowledge or is it a typo in your post ?

Comment: Cut & Paste Typo but I'll check the code. It was working as I mentioned. Thanks for the attempt

Comment: Is this still an issue ? Were u able to figure out ?

Comment: This is a valid issue. I also have the Walmart API running on a set time every hour and every now and then the Acknowledge Orders post doesn't work. It is random and a few hours later the Order Acknowledge works fine. I have not found a workaround yet for this issue except to re-try at a later time. I think the Walmart server has its own issues...